# DataTable.Merge() lose column from main table

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have this code:

```
public void UcitajTargete()
{
    DataTable kom = new DataTable();
    DataTable mag = new DataTable();

    using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(M.Baza.connectionKomercijalno2018))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter("SELECT PPID, NAZIV, MOBILNI FROM PARTNER ORDER BY NAZIV", con))
        {
            da.Fill(kom);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(M.Baza.connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter("SELECT PPID, POSLEDNJI_PUT_PROPAGIRAN FROM PARTNER WHERE(POSLEDNJI_PUT_PROPAGIRAN >= 0)", con))
        {
            da.Fill(mag);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    kom.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { kom.Columns["PPID"] };
    mag.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { mag.Columns["PPID"] };

    kom.Merge(mag);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = mag;
}
```

So I want to merge these two tables on `PPID` and to get these columns as result: `PPID | NAZIV | MOBILNI | POSLEDNJI_PUT_PROPAGIRAN`.

With current code i get `PPID, POSLEDNJI_PUT_PROPAGIRAN`

Comment: Try `mag.Merge(kom);` instead.

Comment: Tried. It returns only columns from `kom` data table

Comment: Then: `kom.Merge(mag, False, MissingSchemaAction.Add);` should do it.

Comment: Well i will try that too but i found problem. As you can see in code i do `kom.Merge(mag);` but i set `datasorce = mag` instead of `kom`...

Comment: Well that's that then